# Opening name change of one game at Chess.com

Tags: opening, online-chess, sicilian-defense, terminology, english-opening

Here are the first few moves of a game that I played at chess.com and the name of the openings is shown by the system:

1. c4 **(English Opening)** c5 **(English Opening; Symmetrical Variation)**
2. Nc3 Nc6 **(English Opening; Symmetrical, Two Knights Variation)**
3. g3 **(English Opening; Symmetrical, Two Knights, Fianchetto Variation)** Nf6
4. Bg2 **(English Opening; Angelo-Indian Defense)** g6 **(English Opening; Symmetrical, Two Knights, Fianchetto Variation)**
5. e4 Bg7 **(English Opening; Fianchetto, Ultra-Symmetrical, Botinivik System)**
6. d3 **(English Opening; Fianchetto, Ultra-Symmetrical Line)** O-O **(English Opening, Angelo-Indian, Queen's Knight Variation)**
7. Nge2 **(Sicilian Defence, Staunton-Cochrane System)** d6
8. O-O **(English Opening; Fianchetto, Ultra-Symmetrical, Botinivik System)**

Why did the name of the opening of this game change back and forth so many times in the first few moves? I am particularly amazed that we entered Sicilian Defence at move 7 and came back to English at move 8.

Answer (score 2):

Before a sufficient number of moves is played, the exact name of the opening cannot be determined. And the key term to answer your question is [transpositions](/questions/tagged/transpositions):

> ... is a sequence of moves that results in a position that may also be reached by another, more common sequence of moves. Transpositions are particularly common in the opening, where a given position may be reached by different sequences of moves ([Wiki on chess transpositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_(chess))).

So, `c4` at move 1 is commonly referred as the *English opening* family; however, certain Sicilian (and other ones!) defense positions can be reached from it (soundly or unsoundly — is a different question). Moreover, in many cases there is no established convention on how to call a position (especially when amateur players play the opening); hence, some choice is made by a website interface, and it might be that another website can make a different choice for the same position.